# how to edit an existing row value on the basis of the previous row value in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset as below:

```
date time value
20141102 1420 0
20141102 1425 2
20141103 1430 N/A
20141103 1435 N/A
20141104 1440 2
20141104 1445 N/A
20141105 1450 N/A
20141105 1455 2
```

But I want to edit the column value.
1. I want the value to be 0 instead of 2 if the previous value is N/A. The desired output should be like this:

```
 date time value
 20141102 1420 0
 20141102 1425 2
 20141103 1430 N/A
 20141103 1435 N/A
 20141104 1440 0
 20141104 1445 N/A
 20141105 1450 N/A
 20141105 1455 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.where` + `shift`

```
df['value']=np.where(df.value.isnull().shift()&df.value.eq(2),0,df.value)
df
Out[593]: 
       date  time  value
0  20141102  1420    0.0
1  20141102  1425    2.0
2  20141103  1430    NaN
3  20141103  1435    NaN
4  20141104  1440    0.0
5  20141104  1445    NaN
6  20141105  1450    NaN
7  20141105  1455    0.0
```